# Receive data only when client sends the data

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing an application in which i will send the mouse coordinates when mouse is clicked through socket.

It will be received by server and will be further processed.
As server is running on while loop it is always expecting client to send data which is false.

So how to receive the data only when client send the data to server otherwise it should be running itself in while loop?

Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried. Show your codes

Comment: What kind of Connection do you want to use? A standing connection between client and server or do you want the client to reconnect? If you have a standing (permanent) connection why do you want the server to use a while loop rather than waiting / blocking until new data has arrived?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but from what I understand you want a server that will work only when a client sends a request.

This is basically impossible, it's the same as if you would want to open a store and you would want the store open ONLY when there are clients. You can't do it, there would have to be time the store is open and there without any buyers actively in it.

Having any further input on how to solve your issue also depends on the technology you're using (are both the server and client written in Java? are you already using any frameworks or libraries?).